# ASP.MVC 2.0 How display Blank textbox for Model property of Integer when integer value is zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code:

`<div class="editor-field">`

`<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyId) %>`

`<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyId) %>

<`/div>

The 'MyId' property of the model is of type integer.

When the form is in 'Create' mode, MyId value is 0. How can I, prevent 0 displaying and rather render the textbox with an empty string / blank / no value?

I have tried various forms of String.Format without success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you could use the `TextBox()` method instead, which allows you to specify the value to be shown:

```
<%: Html.TextBox("MyId", model.MyId == 0 ? "" : model.MyId.ToString()) %>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. That was the answer.

Answer (score 26):

You could use a nullable integer:

```
public int? MyId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Wouldn't have suggested it otherwise.